# Counting Coprime Numbers in a range:

Tags: number-theory

I know that $\varphi(n)$ is the number of positive integers less than $n$ that are coprime to $n$. What I don't know is how to solve a related, but seemingly reverse problem.

How do I count the number of integers coprime to $n$ in a range $\left[a,b\right]$ where $n < a < b$?

I know that I can take the prime divisors of $n$ and do some inclusion-exclusion action on the values $a$ and $b$ to count but I'm wondering if there isn't a better method. If $n$ is smooth, this can get rather lengthy.

Comments??

Thanks!

Comment: Let's call that number $\varphi(n,a,b)$ for short, and forget the assumption $n<a$. A useful observation is that it is sufficient to know $\varphi(n,a,b)$ whenever $a<b\le n$. Indeed, since being coprime with $n$ is invariant $\text{mod }n$, one can reduce to thas case after adding $\lfloor {b-a+1\over n}\rfloor\cdot\varphi(n)$.

Comment: The inclusion-exclusion method for the number coprime to $n$ in $[1,k]$ gives you $$T(n,k) = \sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) \lfloor k/d \rfloor $$
which is OEIS sequence A078401 (for $k \le n$).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli how does this work if $b-a$ is much greater than $n$?

Comment: I have worked this out in all cases. @G.Sassatelli, If you'd answerify your comment I'll accept it.
$\varphi(n,a,b)$ for any range is $\gamma \varphi(n) + R$ where $\gamma$ is $floor\left((b-a)/n\right)$ or one greater if $a > b $ mod $n$.
And where $R$ is the remaining bits that you have to keep track of unaccounted for. (For example the coprime integers up to $a$ mod $n$, and after $b$ mod $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this solution should be better than inclusion-exclusion, what about you take primes from factorization of n and run Eratosthene's sieve on $[a,b]$ using just these primes?

Comment: Rather than bothering to factor $n$, if $b - a$ is small enough to do that you might as well just compute $\gcd(n,x)$ for each $x$ in the interval.

Comment: @RobertIsrael That method works for small $b-a$ but I'm interested in the case where $b-a$ is very large.

Comment: @JukesOnYou, this seems like a promising method. I'm not sure how to do it, I'll have to ponder this a moment.