# A combinatoric $gcd$ problem

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Let $Q(L)$ be the number of pairs of numbers $m , n$ such that $gcd(m,n) = 1$ and $m$ and $n$ are of different pairity, where $m$ is even and $n$ is odd, and $m^2 + n^2$ $\le$ $ L$.

$$Q(L) = \sum_{gcd(m,n)=1 \atop {m\space even\atop {n\space odd}}}^{m^2+n^2 \le L}1$$

The number of these pairs corresponds to the number of ***primitive*** pythagorean triplets with a hypotenuse $\le$ $L$, in which $gcd(a,b,c) = 1$ and $a,b,c$ are the sides of the triangle.

If $L$ is small I can easily enumerate the number of these pairs with a computer, but given sufficiently large $L$ this becomes inefficient. I've been thinking for quite some time but I couldn't myself find a formula or an algorithm, though I have a feeling there is a simple combinatorial approach to this. So is there an efficient way to count these pairs?

**EDIT**

In an attempt to solve the above question, I've come up with an idea to perhaps simplify it. Define $T(P,L)$ to be the amount of numbers $\le$ $L$ that are coprime to $P$ , that is:

$$T(P,L) = \sum_{k=1\atop {gcd(k,P)=1}}^L1$$

Solving this, I assume, will be a significant step in solving the original question of $Q(L)$ in my approach.

Also, if you have another approach in your mind to solving this problem, other than the $GCD$ approach, it'll be excellent as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Trying to solve https://projecteuler.net/problem=540 ? :)

Comment: Haha, yeah. It basically reduces to this problem. I wanna try this approach before the ternary tree with the 3 matrices as I don't quite understand it very well. @MartinR

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292042/counting-coprime-numbers-in-a-range.

Comment: I've looked at it, but I think it's a different problem than mine, by more than one aspect.. That is unless you know something that I haven't yet noticed. @MartinR

Comment: Even without the side conditions on $m$ and $n$, enumerating (exactly) the number of lattice points inside a circle of fixed radius is not easy.

Comment: Well, perhaps the GCD approach to this problem isn't the best. But a simple and efficient solution to this problem must exist, and it (of course) counts the number of pairs described in my question along the way. @GregMartin

Comment: If you want to solve that project euler problem you would be better of reading the wikipedia pythagorean triples page carefully

Comment: I'll read it right away. Could u hint a bit further though? Is the $GCD$ approach the right way or it cannot work? @dREaM